# Can I safely store passwords inside the source of a CGI script?

Tags: perl

I am sending email with Perl through Gmail with the help of [Email::Send::SMTP::Gmail](http://p3rl.org/Email%3a%3aSend%3a%3aSMTP%3a%3aGmail). The script is stored as `send.pl`. I am accesing it throgh `localhost/send.pl`. I have to type in my password to my Gmail account in this Perl script and then access it from my browser.

Is there any way that anyone browsing to this site can obtain my Gmail password?

My code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Email::Send::SMTP::Gmail;
my $mail = Email::Send::SMTP::Gmail->new(
    -smtp  => 'gmail.com',
    -login => 'whateveraddress@gmail.com',
    -pass  => 'whatever_pass'
);
$mail->send(
    -to          => 'target@xxx.com',
    -subject     => 'Hello!',
    -charset     => 'KOI8-R',
    -verbose     => '1',
    -body        => 'Just testing it',
    -attachments => 'full_path_to_file'
);
$mail->bye;
```

Comment: Keeping your password in plain text in a file that is readable on the internet seems like a very poor solution.

Comment: user1092042, I see that you added new code to the question that turns it into a completely different topic. Please do not do this, each topic on Stack Overflow must stand alone, or else this site does not work well. I have reverted the question to how it was before. Your text still exists at http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/10796356/4 - please copy this text and [open a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) with it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So long as the server remains properly configured, no, your password is safe.

It is, however, a good idea to keep the password in a configuration file outside of the site root and read it from your script rather then embedding it in the script itself. That way, if the server configuration is changed and starts serving up the script raw instead of executing it, your password is still safe.

Comment: Any idea how i would read the password from the configuration file. Are there any tutorials explaining how to do this.

Comment: Use [Config::Any](https://metacpan.org/module/Config::Any) or one of the config modules listed in its dependancies.

Comment: I am currently using the code updated in my question.However it simply print an array reference and not the password itself.PLease take a look at my edited question